# pykeepass is not returning the password attribute

Tags: python

I have been tinkering with pykeepass most of the day in hopes of utilizing it with keepass. I am able to return lists of the current groups and pull the title and name from current entries in my kbdx file.

When I attempt to retrieve the password, I get an error saying "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'password'". I only today installed this python library so I assume it is current. Here is my code:

```
import pykeepass

db_path = r'H:\personal_kp.kdbx'
keyfile = r'h:\personal_kp.keyx'

kp = pykeepass.PyKeePass(db_path,password=None,keyfile=keyfile)
group = kp.find_groups(name='Network')
print(group)
group = kp.find_groups_by_name(group_name='Network')
print(group)

entry = kp.find_entries(title='system1')
xyz = kp.find_entries_by_title(title='system2')
xx = kp.entries
testpwd = xyz.password 
print(f'Entry for ws1p1 = {entry}')
print(f'Entry for ws2p3 = {xyz}')
print(f'xx result {xx}')
print(f'pass {testpwd}')
print('Number of entries',len(kp.entries))
```

The readme on the pykeepass git page shows password retrieval. Am I missing a trick perhaps?
https://github.com/libkeepass/pykeepass

Comment: You should provide a full stacktrace for error messages, if your question is about them. However, it seems likely the error occurs on `xyz.password`. `xyz` was assigned the return value of a call to `.find_entries_by_title()` and the name suggests this returns not just a single entry, but a collection of entries. The error suggests that it returns a `list` of them. So, you can't just `xyz.password`, but you could `xyz[0].password` if there's at least one entry in the list.

Comment: You should try adding a `print(f'xyz={xyz}')` before the line where you have `xyz.password` to see the content of what that variable contains / that method returns.

Comment: adding print(f'xyz={xyz}') just before my xyz.password returns the "group/title" as expected.
referencing item 0 as if an array was being returned seems to be the trick. I would not have guessed that based on what is on the github site for pykeepass.  testpwd = xyz[0].password works.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a full stacktrace for error messages, if your question is about them.

However, it seems likely the error occurs on `xyz.password`. `xyz` was assigned the return value of a call to `.find_entries_by_title()` here:

```
xyz = kp.find_entries_by_title(title='system2')
```

And the name suggests this returns not just a single entry, but a collection of entries. The error suggests that it returns a `list` of them.

The [documentation of the package](https://pykeepass.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) isn't great, so it's not easy to find the actual answer there. But from [the source code](https://github.com/pschmitt/pykeepass/blob/master/pykeepass/pykeepass.py), it would seem that the result is likely the result of a call to `_find`, which finally returns the result of a call `_xpath()` - and that is indeed a list (unless `first` was set).

So, you can't just get `xyz.password`, but you could get `xyz[0].password` if there's at least one entry in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply `first=True` to `find_entries` so that the returned result is either an Entry or None.  The idiomatic way to do this is as follows

```py
xyz = kp.find_entries(title='system2', first=True)

if xyz is not None:
    print(f'password: {xyz.password}')
```

Avoid using `find_entries_by_XXX` and `find_groups_by_XXX` as they are deprecated.